# 2D array not changing when assigning new value

Tags: java

I am trying to make a checkers game in the java console and when trying to get a piece to move, the 2d array that houses the game board does not change. The method movePiece takes three arguments, the 'move code' (1-4 which corresponds to the movement the player intends to make, 1 is up right, 2 is up left, 3 is down left, 4 is up right) and the x and y values of the piece the player wants to move. The method is called and executes fine, but when the board is printed out(using the printBoard method) it doesn't show any changes made.

```
public class Board {
    private char gameBoard[][] =  {{'0','b','0','b','0','b','0','b'},{'b','0','b','0','b','0','b','0',},{'0','b','0','b','0','b','0','b'},{'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'},{'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'},{'r','0','r','0','r','0','r','0',},{'0','r','0','r','0','r','0','r'},{'r','0','r','0','r','0','r','0'}};;

    public char[][] getBoard() {
        return gameBoard;
    }

    public void movePiece(int move,int startingX, int startingY){
        int wantedX, wantedY;
        switch(move){
            case 1:
                wantedX = startingX + 1;
                wantedY = startingY + 1;

                break;
            case 2:
                wantedX = startingX - 1;
                wantedY = startingY + 1;
                break;
            case 3:
                wantedX = startingX - 1;
                wantedY = startingY - 1;
                break;
            case 4:
                wantedX = startingX + 1;
                wantedY = startingY - 1;
                break;
            default:
                wantedX = 0;
                wantedY = 0;
                break;
        }
        this.gameBoard[wantedX][wantedY] = this.gameBoard[startingX][startingY];
        this.gameBoard[startingX][startingY] = '0';
    }

    public int countPieces(char color){
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < gameBoard.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < gameBoard[i].length; i++){
                if(gameBoard[i][j] == color)
                    count++;
            }
        }
        return count;   
    }

    public void printBoard(){
        for(int i = 0; i < gameBoard.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < gameBoard[i].length; j++){
                System.out.print(gameBoard[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}




public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.print("Beginning test\n");
        Board board = new Board();
        board.printBoard();
        System.out.println("Moving piece at (2,0) to (3,1)");
        board.movePiece(1, 2, 0);
        board.printBoard();
    }

}
```

Comment: There's no piece at (2,0).  I think your program is working fine; you just need to give your method the right input.

Comment: Also, you need to check which way is up and which way is down.  Since your print method prints row 0 at the top, that means when you add 1 to X you are actually going "down", which means that case 1 is going "down right" instead of "up right".  (If `X` is supposed to be the column number, as if it were the X-axis, then you aren't doing that right either, since you're using `wantedX` and `startingX` as row numbers.)